# 4 constants; each less then the other one

Tags: php, constants

Everyone seems to be familiar with the following concept:

```
if
a > b
and
b > c
then
a > c
```

this, apparently, doesn't work in PHP, I heard a rumour that there are 4 constants, each less then the other one, like in a cycle. Does anyone know what these are?

EDIT:

found solution using constants:

```
define('A', 1);
define('B', "a");
define('C', "2");

var_dump(A > B); //true
var_dump(B > C); //true
var_dump(C > A); //true
```

Comment: A technical rumor ? Interesting !!

Comment: It probably involves type conversions.

Comment: Specific examples are needed. It is possibly due to a misunderstanding of [PHP's insane type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) or a misunderstanding of [type comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three values suffice:

```
$a = INF;
$b = array();
$c = (object)array();
var_dump($a < $b);
var_dump($b < $c);
var_dump($c < $a);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Taken from [here](http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/52).